# Can one webpage have multiple form and elements with same id

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a webpage with multiple forms and with each form having the same set of data like empid, empname, etc... Can i have multiple form and the id of each field same in each form(form id different).

Comment: no... you can't have...

Comment: any solution for this? Actually i want to fetch data from database and review it and change it if required and then submit the form to save data.

Comment: you can have duplicate names.... why do you want duplicate ids

Comment: if with name i can submit the form and get the post data then it will be fine with me @ArunPJohny

Comment: I just want the data only for the form submitted. Not for all the records

Comment: when a form is submitted the params are sent based on input name not by id

Comment: if you have multiple form's make sure they are not nested

Comment: "Can", yes. "May", no. If you have multiple forms, use duplicate names instead. Form controls must have a name to be successful (i.e. be sent when the form is submitted), so just use that.

Comment: If you use duplicate IDs things like `document.getElementByID(myID)` will at best provide unreliable results, as it expects no more than 1 element with a given ID.

Comment: " Actually i want to fetch data from database and review it and change it if required and then submit the form to save data." Why does this need more than one form on the page?

Comment: @JonP I need it to review the data and edit it and again save back the data. The data is group of records like employee and its details. I will send back only the data of single employee which is edited

Answer (score 2):

No.  That is disallowed-id must be unique across all elements regardless of type.  But, sites do it anyway and the browser doesn't care as long as it's not actually used to find something.